# rxvt-unicode-256color (Debian, 9.22-6): braille characters only shown after showing arabic character

Tags: terminal, fonts, unicode, rxvt

I'm trying to display braille characters in my urxvt terminal, e.g. I'd like to see a dot when running `echo -e "\u2840"`.

To my confusion, this only works if I run `echo -e "\u0641"` first in that terminal window. Running this after trying to show braille characters does NOT fix it. When it does not work I see squares instead of unicode characters.

The shown commands are the only commands I started in the terminal windows.
[image]

(`UTF-8-demo.txt` is taken from  https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt)

My .Xdefaults:

```
! vim: set ts=8 sw=8 sts=8:
URxvt*background: rgba:0000/0000/0000/abab
URxvt.font: xft:monospace:size=7:antialias=true
URxvt.boldFont: xft:monospace:bold:size=7:antialias=true
URxvt.color4:           RoyalBlue
URxvt*color12:                  #5c5cff
URxvt*depth: 32
URxvt.eightBitInput:            false
URxvt.foreground:               #ffffff
URxvt*keysym.End: \033[4~
URxvt*keysym.Home: \033[1~
URxvt.matcher.button: 3
URxvt.matcher.pattern.1: \\bwww\\.[\\w-]\\.[\\w./?&@#-]*[\\w/-]
URxvt.MetaSendsEscape:          true
URxvt.modifier: alt
URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,matcher
URxvt.saveLines: 8192
URxvt.scrollBar: false
URxvt.termName:xterm-256color
URxvt:urlLauncher: firefox
```